# AS3: The precise algorithm in Papervision3D?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, papervision3d

When you use Graphics.drawTriangles() and Graphics.beginBitmapFill() to draw two triangles to create a rectangle face, when the face is not square or rectangle, but rather a trapezoid, or an irregular shape, the bitmap used to fill the face is distorted. In order to correct the distortion, Papervision3D has a Boolean property precise. But how does it work?

Thanks! :)

Comment: I'd consider not using Papervision3D if you have a choice. The project has been dead for several years (hasn't even been updated for true 3d capabilities in Flash Player 10) and you're unlikely to get any support. It's going to be very slow compared to other options as well.

Comment: I know, I know. i hate papervision3D but I still want to know how does it correct the distortion. Do you have any idea?